# Showing Posts if non are found

Tags: posts, search

I'm trying to write my search.php that it shows the posts when searched for but when non post match the search, it just shows all posts again (like on the index).

This is my code at the moment. It doesn't work, but also doesn't crash.

```
 <?php get_header(); ?>
<main id="content">
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <a class="entry-title resultsfound"><?php printf( esc_html__( 'All search Results for %s', 'blankslate'), get_search_query() ); ?></a>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
      <?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>

      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?>
        <?php comments_template(); ?>
      <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
    </main>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Remove lines 10,12,13 and see what happens. https://pastebin.com/s7YPyUbQ

Comment: I would also create a template part named empty and use that to customize my "no result found" page. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/